# Getting an empty response from the Facebook api for ratings

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the reviews of a Facebook page via the Facebook API.

```
$fb = new Facebook([
   'app_id'     => 123,
   'app_secret' => 'abcd',
   'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
]);

$reponse = $fb->get("/123/ratings",$accessToken);
```

I'm getting an empty array for the result, even if I'm sur that the page contain some reviews.

```
{"data":[]}
```

Comment: Do `/me/ratings` and use a page access token for that page